# Vuejs v-model is not working with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using laravel chat with vue js.

I am getting an error when I use v-model in laravel.

Vuejs is also not detected via VueJs Plugin.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <input type="text" class="from-control" v-model="message">
    </div>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</body>
```

I have following in my `app.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app', 
  data:{
      message:'',
      chat:{
          message:[]
      }
   },methods:{
      send(){
         if(this.message.length !=0){
            this.chat.message.push(this.message); 
         }
     }
   }}); 
Vue.config.devtools = true
```

[image]

Comment: Did you run `npm run dev`?

Comment: Yes , When i remove v-model='message' in the input that time will work properly

Comment: @JigneshPrajapati why you add defer in <script> tag?

Comment: I don't know but i have remove that before same issue no luck

Comment: okay. why you add Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue')); ?

Comment: try with <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" ></script>

Comment: yes try it but not any changed 
if you want to anydesk or teamviewer

Comment: @JigneshPrajapati try with changing name of variable message in v-model and data.

Comment: I have done before same

Comment: @JigneshPrajapati try with adding form tag before input tag.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya No that is not required to work with v-model. You can see in this [example](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Text)

Answer (score 0):

You're using single ' quote in v-model, So Vue could be taking it as a string, Try it with double quotes like this:

`<div id="app">
    <input type="text" class="from-control" v-model="message">
 </div>`

Comment: @JigneshPrajapati Okay then at least use double quotes in your question so we know that you've already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

did you include below line into your app.js file:

```
 import vmodal from 'vue-js-modal';
```

for more infomations check: [Vuejs v-model with Laravel](https://therichpost.com/vue-laravel-tutorial-part-8-vuemodal)

Comment: You know he's talking about `v-model` [directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model) right?

Comment: I think you're confusing `model` with `modal`.

"You can use the v-model directive to create two-way data bindings on form input, textarea, and select elements. It automatically picks the correct way to update the element based on the input type."